# MultiplicativeOrder understanding

Tags: number-theory

According to specification, this should find the smallest integer $m$ such that $10^m \, mod \, 16 = 0$, or return unevaluated if there is no such integer.

`MultiplicativeOrder[10, 16, {0}]`

> `MultiplicativeOrder[10, 16, {0}]`

But such integer does exist, for example four:

`Divisible[10^4, 16]`

> `True`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The equality $k^m = 0 \mod n$ is well defined, but the integer $0$ does not belong to a multiplicative group. I think this is the reason why `MultiplicativeOrder` remains unevaluated in this case.

Comment: @xavier Can I replace 0 with 1 for example (default remainder), and transform the arguments somehow so the initial equality still holds?

Comment: @BoLe `MultiplicativeOrder[x, 16]` should evaluate for any integer `x` where `GCD[x, 16] == 1`, i.e. `x` must be an odd integer.